# Prevent maximum call stack size exceeded in jQuery validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I've two methods in jQuery validator that need to call each other without end in a 'maximum call stack size exceeded' exception.

I need that because if I write into one of this input box and it goes in error, when I write in the second input box I need to hide the error of the first input box.

This is my simplified code:

```
       $.validator.addMethod("a", function (value, element) {
            var a = $("#a").val();
            var b = $("#b").val();

            if (parseInt(a) > parseInt(b)) {
                return false;
            } else {
                $('#b').valid(); //!!!!
                return true;
            }
            return true;
        }, "error");

        $.validator.addMethod("b", function (value, element) {
            var a = $("#a").val();
            var b = $("#b").val();

            if (parseInt(b) < parseInt(a)) {
                return false;
            } else {
                $('#a').valid(); //!!!!
                return true;
            }
            return true;
        }, "error");
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xf6qvxyb/1/?

Comment: and if there is also 'c' that must be greater than 'a' and 'b'?